# Relation between symplectic manifolds and (almost) complex manifolds

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry, complex-manifolds, almost-complex

I'm a beginner in symplectic geometry, and I recently learned that every symplectic manifold has an almost complex structure.

I am curious about the converse. Does every almost complex manifold have a symplectic structure? If not, then does every complex manifold have a symplectic structure? I tried to search but I couldn't find relevant results. (If these are true) is there a reference for proofs of these results?

Comment: The Hopf surface is a compact complex manifold that doesn’t admit a symplectic structure (because $H^2(X,\mathbb R) =0$), so the answer to both questions is “no”.

Comment: Every almost-complex manifold admits and almost-symplectic structure, and vice versa (Ramanan, exercise 7.1.19). Since symplectic manifolds are almost-symplectic, they are also almost-complex. An almost-complex (or complex) manifold thus admits and almost-symplectic structure, but not a symplectic structure. The difference is whether the symplectic form is closed; a cohomology argument (such as Ivo Tarek's answer) would thus show this failing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a counter-example for "almost complex": the sphere $\Bbb S^6$.

It has an almost-complex structure induced by multiplication of octonions. Namely, $\Bbb R^7$ is the only Euclidean space (apart from $\Bbb R^3$) carrying a binary cross product. If $\Sigma \subseteq \Bbb R^7$ is a orientable hypersurface with unit normal field $N\colon \Sigma \to \Bbb S^6$, define, for each $x \in \Sigma$, $J_x\colon T_x\Sigma \to T_x\Sigma$ by $J_x(v) = N(x)\times v$. In particular, one may take $\Sigma = \Bbb S^6$ itself.

But $\Bbb S^6$ does not carry any symplectic structure, for topological reasons. Namely, all even order cohomologies of a compact symplectic manifold must be non-trivial as a consequence of Stokes's theorem, but $H^2_{\rm dR}(\Bbb S^6) = 0$.

It is an open problem whether $\Bbb S^6$ has integrable almost-complex structures. And if I recall correctly, the almost-complex structures defined on hypersurfaces of $\Bbb R^7$ via the above recipe are *never* integrable. What's more, there's a [result due to Claude LeBrun](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1987-101-01/S0002-9939-1987-0897084-7/S0002-9939-1987-0897084-7.pdf) saying that $\Bbb S^6$ does not admit integrable almost-complex structures compatible with the standard round metric (he argues that if this were the case, $\Bbb S^6$ would be Kahler, and hence symplectic, against the above paragraph).

Complex examples are a bit more complicated, but apparently [Calabi-Eckmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Eckmann_manifold) manifolds fit the bill. They're complex, but one can show (e.g. using the Künneth formula) that a product $\Bbb S^p \times \Bbb S^q$, with $p,q \geq 1$, carries a symplectic structure if and only if $p=q=1$ or $p=q=2$.